# Is it possible to run azure Iotedge on a coral dev board with mendel linux?

Tags: azure, google-coral, mendel-os

I am trying to get my coral dev board connected to the azure cloud. I was following this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux and everything worked fine until the "sudo apt-get install iotedge" step. The output of this command:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package iotedge**

the command "apt list -a iotedge" lists:

iotedge/stretch 1.0.9.5-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.9.4-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.9.3-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.9.2-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.9.1-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.9-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.8-2 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.8-1 armhf
iotedge/stretch 1.0.7.1-1 armhf

I already tried several options like running "sudo apt-get install iotedge=1.0.8* libiothsm-std=1.0.8*"

On this website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support you can find supported OS and i dont know if mendel Linux counts as a debian?
Is it possible to get the azure iotedge running on a coral dev board?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64317182/is-it-possible-to-run-azure-iotedge-on-a-coral-dev-board-with-mendel-linux

Comment: what? you linked to the same question.

Comment: Same question asked twice by the same user polluting this platform.

Answer (score 0):

the `armhf` indicates that the package you installed was for arm32 architecture, while the board has arm64 (aarch64).

Maybe you installed the wrong package or azure-iot doesn't support aarch64?